# Bootstrap datepicker not opennig with jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I just want to write a jquery method for datepicker. I am facing an issue.
I have spent a lot of time on this but couldn't fix it.

This is my html code:

```
<html:text property="createDt" styleId="createDt" onclick="showCalenderDt(this)" styleClass="form-control mandatory"></html:text>
```

But these are not working:-

// Only for date

```
var dtFmt =  "yyyy-MM-dd"     
window.showCalenderDt = function(id){
          var dateFormat = dtFmt.replace("MM","mm");
          $('.dateTimePicker').datetimepicker('remove');
         $("#" + get_id)..datetimepicker({
              format: dateFormat,
              startView: 2,
              minView: 2,
              autoclose: true,
              todayBtn: false             
          });

      }
```

//for  Date and time

```
var dtTmFmt =  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"      
window.showCalenderDtTm = function(id){
          var dateTimeFormat = dtTmFmt.replace("MM","mm");
          dateTimeFormat = dateTimeFormat.replace("mm:ss","ii:ss");
          $('.dateTimePicker').datetimepicker('remove');
          $("#" + get_id)..datetimepicker({
              format: dateTimeFormat,
              startView: 2,
              autoclose: true,
              minuteStep: 5,
              todayBtn: false
          });

      }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you importing jqueryui js and css? I always forget.

Comment: yes, I am doing this, all others are working fine

Comment: If you post the HTML/CSS/JS here or a jsfiddle, I can take a look and figure it out for ya. :)